# Búsquedas relacionadas en laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hola estaba buscando una consulta que me devuelva una lista de busquedas relacionadas, a las busqueda realizada.

```
$relacionadas = Search::where('search', 'like', '%' . $request['search'] . '%')->get();
```

Yo utilizo esa query, almaceno en $relacionadas las que son parecidas, pero no me trae ninguna. Ejemplo:

Pongo abogado de derecho familiar, y quiero que me aparezcan "abogado de derecho civil" pero esa query no me la trae. Como podré hacer para que me retorne los que son "parecidos" o esten "relacionados" de algún modo.

En la tabla columna "search" guardo las búsquedas realizadas,
y $request['search'] es la búsqueda actual.

Gracias.

Comment: Prueba de este modo `where('search', 'sounds like', ......) Es decir sustituye tú like por este operador`

Comment: Sigue igual bro

Comment: Puede ser que tenga que agarrar el string y sacarle los espacios ?

Comment: La busqueda "abogado de derecho"

Comment: Amigo edite y reverti tu edición pues la respuesta va abajo en la zona de respuestas y no en tu pregunta

Comment: Cuando la publiques contarás con mi +1